# How can I edit the Subject of a CiviCase?

Tags: civicase

Whilst Cases have subjects there appears to be no way to edit via the interface.

Comment: I agree with Graham. It is these small items that cost more for clients to use CiviCRM as they have to pay us to make content changes directly to the database. I have asked for an estimate to determine funding.

Comment: This should have been left as a comment, rather than an answer. Please remember that StackExchange is not a discussion forum.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/5567)

Answer (score 2):

It seems from this [forum post](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=23834.15) that the ability to edit the subject of a CiviCase has not been implemented, and that its implementation should be done by creating a new core/case Activity Type for 'Change Case Subject' so that any change was also tracked on the Case.

That sounds a reasonable improvement, in the meantime it seems the only option is to edit the field in the civicase table - which my brief testing suggests doesn't not bring the wrath of code down upon my head

Comment: That is right Pete, you can do so directly in the database, or with the API I would expect.

Comment: This is precisely the type of absurd issue that I find really riles users and negatively impacts their relationship with CiviCRM

Comment: There is an issue on this dating back a little over a year: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16633 Needs funding. Anyone keen to help out could perhaps make it know in the comments there?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this has been fixed in the new release today for CiviCRM 4.7.19.

Comment: would be good to have a link to jira for this

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9869 and in jira at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20140 and https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16633